# Why is there a semicolon necessary in this loop?

Tags: c++

I've been doing some research for my homework in C++ and I've came across this solution to my task that is literally one line of code. (+ initializing the variables ofcourse).

```
for (; n != 0; n /= 10, ++count) {}
```

My question is, what does the semicolon at the start of the for loop do. We've never covered that with our professor. Is there a different way in how this could've been written perhaps without a semicolon but still using a for loop?

Comment: There's nothing to initialize (it's probably been done prior to that line of code), so whoever wrote that code just skipped that part.

Comment: I think, pre `C89` or `C90`, you couldn't do `for (int n=0; n != 0; n /= 10, ++count) {}`, so, people did it in two steps `int n=0; for (; n != 0; n /= 10, ++count) {}`.

Comment: @JoeyMallone in this instance it's because the "n" variable is actually inputed by the user. I now understand how and why it's made that way.

Comment: Note that if the purpose of this code is to count the digits in a number, it results in 0 for n=0.

Comment: That's exactly what it's for!

Answer (score 4):

This the for loop prototype

```
for(initialization;testExpression; updateStatement)
```

you are just saying there is no initialization needed

Comment: *'increment/decrement'* - don't we have some better wording? You could do anything in this loop part (`for(unsigned int i = 1 << 7; i; i >>= 1)`, so something like `post-loop-action` (sure I know, *that* one, even if describing better, sounds ugly...).

Comment: thanks for the contribution i think this is better ?

Comment: Seems fine now...

Answer (score 2):

The structure of for loop is,

```
for (initialization; condition; increment/decrement) {
    statements;
}
```

So you have done your initialization outside the for loop, so you have to skip that part and just do the condition check!

---

`Is there a different way in how this could've been written perhaps without a semicolon but still using a for loop?`

The answer is **No** if you want to eliminate semicolon and use `for` loop. The semicolon is what separating a statement from being `initialisation` or `condition` or `increment/decrement`. Without a semicolon, it takes the first statement as `initialisation`.

---

Example:

The below code is proper for loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

---

It can be rewritten as,

```
i = 0; // initialisation
for (; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

In the above code, we initialised `i = 0` outside `for` loop, so now we don't have to do anything in the initialization part of for loop. So in order to skip it, and move to condition statement, we added `;`.

---

Which again can be minimized by removing `increment/decrement` step,

```
i = 0; // initialisation
for (; i < 10;) {
    printf("%d", i);
    i = i + 1; // increment
}
```

---

And as mentioned by [Aconcagua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312382/aconcagua) in comments, the final minimal version of the `for` loop can look like this,

```
i = 0; // initialisation
for (; ;) {
    if(i >= 10) { // condition
        break;
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    i = i + 1; // increment
}
```

---

Comment: Minimal? Not yet: `for(;;) { if(i >= 10) break; /* ... */ }`

Comment: Can I add it in to answer for the understanding of OP? I will tag credit for you!

Comment: Well, sure you can...

Answer (score 1):

Any part of the `for` loop `for(init; cond; step)` may be omitted if it is not needed. `for(;;)`, for example, is a pretty idiomatic "infinite loop" construct in C and C++. What you're seeing here is the "init" step being left out.

Answer (score 1):

The for keyword in C++ requires a certain number of parameters.

```
for (initialization_statement; condition_statement; increment_statement) {}
```

The initialization statement can be ommited if you do not wish to declare a new variable or affect the value of an existing variable.

However, you still have to write the first semicolon, to indicate that initialization_statement is to be ignored.